Changing Serial Port Parity at Run time Python Serial
Hi i am working with python serial project i want to change the serial port parity value at runtime it is not working properly especially in odd parity mode it is not sending correct data
import serial
import  time
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0
   )
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_ODD
    ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0x01]))
    ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0x02]))
    ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0x03]))
    ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0x01]))
    ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0x02]))
    ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0x03]))
    time.sleep(2)

In above code i am sending three bytes of data with Odd and Even parity while sending i am  able receive the Even parity data with correct value but in odd parity mode it is not transmitting correct values
for even parity at the receiver end i am getting 01 02 03
for odd parity at receiver end i am getting some time 01 12 03 some time 01 08 03 some time 81 02 03
guide me to change the parity of the serial port at run time

Have you tried doing a sleep for maybe a second after changing the parity? Just in case it needs a little while to work on it.

I tried up to 25 seconds delay but no use

@AndrewMorton after appending delay also not working

Have you got an oscilloscope to check if the correct bits are being sent? I'm wondering if the receiver is confused as changing parity mid-stream is an unusual thing to do.

@AndrewMorton  i am checking the received bytes by another laptop. i am keep the parity as odd for 1 minute  and keep the parity as even for 1 minute but even parity data is coming properly not odd parity data

Does the receiver read the data correctly if both ends are set to odd parity and there is no even parity?

@AndrewMorton I am sending the data by python serial is there any issue with python serial for odd parity and even parity mixing because if i am maintaining the odd parity only the data received properly but if i am mixing the odd and even parity it is not working

How does the receiver "know" that the parity has been changed?

@AndrewMorton Yes if i am maintaining both the send and receive end with odd parity it is working fine

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You have neglected to provide any hardware details of your setup. In my experience PC hardware (e.g. a 16550A UART) and USB serial adapters (e.g. a FTDI USB-to-RS232 converter) have not been reliable in transmitting and/or receiving serial frames of an 8-bit data plus a parity bit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193363/stty-serial-port-settings-for-parity-not-persistent/57318783#57318783 IOW you could be testing with both an unreliable sender and an unreliable reader. You have no means of determining which end is at fault, and your assertions are flawed.
